# Copying SSH files to another machine

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have created a .ssh folder in my new machine and copied id_rsa and id_rsa.pub from an older machine.
When I tried to ssh then I am getting below error

> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @
>   WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
>   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
>   Permissions 0644 for '/Users/adityasingh/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open. It
>   is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
>   This private key will be ignored. Load key
>   "/Users/adityasingh/.ssh/id_rsa": bad permissions

I checked diffrent articles and post then I got to know that i have to change my permission of id_rsa. Then i did

chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

But after this, I am getting a new error related to passphrase key. But I did not select any passphrase key at the time of creation.

Please let me know what should be my next step

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ssh folder and configuration files need to have specific permissions as it states in the error message you pasted here.

When first setting up a machine I usuall use `ssh-keygen -t rsa` this will generate a new key and the necessary file structure with the correct permissions.

So in your case I would recommend you to delete the ~/.ssh folder, generate a new key and then copy over your old keys.

Make sure you `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` your key after copying it.

The correct permissions for all the files, if you want to manually correct it is as follows:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```